# Cannot remove 40 characters named branches from Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch

I have a Gitlab repository with stale branches that I have not noticed before. I think they was created by Gitlab when one of the users made a change to the repository with the build in file editor. They have auto generated names looking like this  `0a9cc10e66e4e7e48bf7a7fc302e5dc25dd21416`.

The issue is, I don't know how to remove this branches.
Gitlab UI return code `400` when I press on the "Delete branch" button.
And git cli failing as well.

`git branch --all`

```
* master
  remotes/origin/0a9cc10e66e4e7e48bf7a7fc302e5dc25dd21416
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

`git push origin --delete 0a9cc10e66e4e7e48bf7a7fc302e5dc25dd21416`

```
remote: GitLab: You cannot create a branch with a 40-character hexadecimal branch name.
```

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Interesting. It looks like GitLab decided to forbid such branch names but failed to account for the deletion pushes. :-)

Comment: Please improve the title of the post such that it summarizes the issue you're describing. The fact that it is a stale branch is irrelevant.

Comment: @Otiel this is indeed solved the issue. Please add an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a GitLab bug. They've added a check in GitLab 12.10 to prevent branches with 40 hexadecimal characters to be created:

See the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/push_rules.html#default-restricted-branch-names):

> #### Default restricted branch names
>
> > Introduced in GitLab 12.10.
>
> By default, GitLab restricts certain formats of branch names for security purposes. 40-character hexadecimal names, similar to Git commit hashes, are prohibited.

But they didn't allow then to delete such branches.

This has been fixed in v14.6, and deleting those legacy branches is now possible again: see the [relevant issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/346478) and [merge request](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/75344).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error response is an active push rule. GitLab offers custom hooks for `git push` events. One such hook is the following security check, activated by default.

> By default, GitLab restricts certain formats of branch names for security purposes. 40-character hexadecimal names, similar to Git commit hashes, are prohibited.
>
> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html#default-restricted-branch-names

*Suggested Solution: Remove/Replace existing push rules.*

This is a premium feature however.

All Projects: Open Admin Area > Push Rules

One Project only: Open Project > Settings > Repository > Tab »Push rules«

*Alternative: Use the API to delete the branch.*

```sh
curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://<your-gitlab-instance>.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/repository/branches/<branch-name>"
```

Comment: Using the REST API returns the same error. It is not a viable alternative.